# Ctrl + . shortcut in Fedora 35 (how to find app-defined shortcuts)

Tags: fedora

I am running Fedora 35. When I press `Ctrl` + `.` in any text field in pretty much any application, it types a lowercase letter "e" that is underlined, which I can typed text afterwards, and when I press `Enter`, the underline and the "e" disappear from the text field, leaving the subsequent text behind. I combed through the keyboard shortcuts and could not find any reference to this `Ctrl` + `.` behavior, and thought it was something that an application was doing. What is this key binding? How can I search all application-defined key bindings to see where this is coming from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This shortcut is used by the [IBus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Input_Bus) input system for "annotate emoji."

You can see the other shortcuts IBus uses by running

```
ibus-setup
```

at the command prompt.